# Import external module ts1.5

Tags: typescript

Does anybody know how to import an external module using Ts1.5 ?

The documentation is not really clear about that and it seem that :

```
import { Reflector } from '../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect';
```

Doesn't work. (Reflect-metadata exposes Reflector.ts and a d.ts file)

I dont know how to process to import external module, even if they are typescript based or es6 based...

Can you help me ?

EDIT :

```
[11:23:40] Compiling TypeScript files using tsc version 1.5.0
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
5,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
5,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
5,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
6,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
6,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
6,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
7,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
7,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
7,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(4
6,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(8
3,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
24,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
05,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
48,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(2
85,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(3
26,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(3
51,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(3
83,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(4
19,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(4
44,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(4
76,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(5
12,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(5
37,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(5
69,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(6
05,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(6
30,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(6
62,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(6
98,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(7
22,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(7
53,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(7
88,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(8
12,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(8
43,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(8
78,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(9
03,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(9
35,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(9
71,21): error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
039,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
269,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
291,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
327,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
337,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
374,46): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WeakMap'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
408,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'.
[11:23:42] [tsc] > F:/nodejs/Sugar.io/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts(1
409,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'.
[11:23:42] Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited with code
:2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `Reflect.ts` is coded (as a non-exported internal module) means you cannot import members from it directly. You'll have to explicitly use the `.d.ts` file and import the library purely for its side-effects:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect-metadata.d.ts" />
import '../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect';
```

Comment: It seems your setup is trying to compile `Reflect.ts` instead of using the already compiled version. Could you check your build setup to make sure the `node_modules` folder is excluded.